# Use derivative of function directly as an anonymous function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I would like to ask, if it is possible to create a anonymous function directly from a return value after using the diff function? Without copy the text from the console and add it manually to a anonymous function.

Eg.

```
xy @(x)=diff(x^2,x);
```

and using afterwards as:
    `xy(3)` and so on.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain what you want, ideally with an example

Comment: Since you seem to be new on this site, you may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html) symbolic function:

```
syms x
f(x) = x^2;    % Equivalent to: f = symfun(x^2,x);
df = diff(f,x) % Since f is a symfun, df will be
df(3)
```

which returns

```
df(x) =

2*x


ans =

6
```